# ACF display image slider with link in frontend

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Pardon my knowledge. I wanted to make a slider via AFC pro, so what i did is:

I made a repeater field with image and url fields.

Am trying to insert the image url and the url field into a slider like this:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('urlfield'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('imagefield'); ?>" style="width:100%"></a>
</div>
```

I think am doing thing wrong so many ways. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning 'URL' and not an 'ARRAY' for image and URL fields in ACF.

Comment: I am sure its returning url, not array.

Comment: Could you post your code for the repeater?

Comment: There is no code, its just the settings there, look here: https://prnt.sc/ybe05r

Comment: I meant the PHP code you have to display repeater.

Comment: Am using the one in my questions post, but am no pro to know if its the correct one or not.